# Using Authorization claims with context dependent roles

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, authorization, claims

First off, I'm quite new in the world of C# Authorization. I've been reading a lot on `IPrincipal`, `IIdentity` `Claim` and what not but I can't map it on to my current application.

Consider: I have three users: Alice, Bob and Charlie and they all have Files.
Say that I am logged in as Alice and Bob and Charlie shared permissions with Alice to their files. Now, Bob gave r/w Access to Alice but Charlie only gave Read access.

The way the API is exposed is via WebApi as REST endpoints (attribute routing). Ideally I'd put another attribute on the endpoint with the claim that it needs for instance:

```
GET    /{user}/files/{fileId} // Gets: Claim("files", "read")
DELETE /{user}/files/{fileId} // Gets: Claim("files", "delete")
```

Problem here is that I don't know how to evaluate these claims since they are dependent on the value of `user`. In the example `user` is either Bob or Charlie while I'm logged in as Alice.

Can anyone help me out how to set up such a system? I'd be happy with some domain-specific terminology or a good blog post.

Comment: Please ask me for clarifications or suggest a radical different approach if you feel that it's warranted =)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice tutorial about the authorization with claims:
http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/

But you could use also used a role based approach and check if the user can access the file using your business logic.

You don't need to specify the user in the route of your API. Keep your route generic:

```
GET    /files/{fileId}
DELETE /files/{fileId}
```

First of all you can create a BaseApiController that will hold the User information for your controllers:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}
```

You can decorate your GET and DELETE methods with a custom authorization attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = ((BaseApiController)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).User;
        //is the user already logged in on the system. This would work perfectly if you have a cookie in your web application authorizing the user
        bool isAuthenticated = principal != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            // Deny request or you could also check the request headers for an authorization token
            return false;
        }

        // Save UserID to be used later in your controllers
        ((BaseApiController)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).UserID = UserID;

        // Authorize user, or you could also check if the user has the correct roles 
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public FilesController : BaseApiController 
{
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int fileID) 
    {
        return filesAccess.getFile(fileID, UserID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Soo, how do you know whether you are looking at Bob or Charlie now that it is not in the routes anymore?

Comment: That would be the "UserID" in my example, which is a Guid, but it could be just a string with Bob or Charlie.